# jQuery: Validate for empty text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

How to validate for empty text input? Required message will show when input textfield is empty.

```
<script>
function LoadData(data){
    var tempdata = data;
    var i=0;
    while (i<tempdata.activity.length) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempdata.activity.length);
        qHint[i] = tempdata.activity[i].hint;
        i++;
    }
}

function hint(data, i){
    $('#mypanel' + (i + 1)).append("<label for=text" + (i + 1) + " id=panel"+ (i + 1)+ " style='margin-top:10%;text-align:center;color:white;'><span id=panelTitle"+ (i + 1) +" >"+ data + "</span></label>");// panel item
    $('#panel' + (i + 1)).append('<input type="text"  name="name" id=text'+ (i + 1) + ' style="text-align: center">');
    $('#mypanel' + (i + 1)).append('<a href="#header" data-role="button" name="submit" id=submit'+ (i + 1)+ ' onClick="submitFunc(' +(i+1)+ ')" data-inline="true" data-rel="close" data-icon="check" style="margin-left:75px;">Submit</a>');
    $('#mypanel' + (i + 1)).append('<a href=#mypanel'+ (i + 1)+ ' data-role="button" id=cancel'+ (i + 1)+ ' data-inline="true" data-rel="close" data-icon="delete2" style="margin-left:75px;">Cancel</a>');
 }

function submitFunc(num){
    $("#text"+num).attr("disabled", true);
    $("#text"+num).attr("readonly", true);
}
</script>
```

Comment: see here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required

Comment: i had read some outside about source, but most of the example the input type is outside the script.

Comment: i did not undetstans.pls can u explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look into using the [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) `val()` which returns the value of, amongst other things, an input of type textbox.

If you are using it within your `submitFunc()` method:

```
function submitFunc(num){
    if($('#text' + num).val() != ''){
        $("#text"+num).attr("disabled", true);
        $("#text"+num).attr("readonly", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.validate.js for this purpose. You'd just need to add required class on the input field.
For example:

```
<input type="text" id="Field1" class="required" />
```

Then on document.ready, just calling `$("#FormName").validate` function would validate that form and its fields for you.
Must note that the input fields to be validated must be part of a form.